# Ошибка 'Unable to load partition metadata from com/amazonaws/partitions/endpoints.json' при деплое в докере

Tags: java, docker, amazon-web-services, amazon, deploy

Делаю проект на Quarkus с использованием aws dynamodb
Пытаюсь запускать через docker
Собирается образ штатно, далее запускается тоже без каких-либо проблем
Но вот стоит мне сделать запрос к серверу, то вылетает ошибка:

```html
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load partition metadata from com/amazonaws/partitions/endpoints.json
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:138)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.access$000(VertxRequestHandler.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:519)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:192)
```

Я выяснил, откуда это берется:
В библиотеке *aws-java-sdk-core* есть класс **PartitionsLoader**, который, собственно, и вываливает данную ошибку.

Я так понимаю, докер не может получить доступ к данной либе?

Мой докерфайл:

```html
## Stage 1 : build with maven builder image with native capabilities
FROM quay.io/quarkus/centos-quarkus-maven:21.0.0-java11 AS build
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app/
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml -B de.qaware.maven:go-offline-maven-plugin:1.2.5:resolve-dependencies
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
USER root
RUN chown -R quarkus /usr/src/app
USER quarkus
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml -Pnative clean package

## Stage 2 : create the docker final image
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal
WORKDIR /work/
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/*-runner /work/application

# set up permissions for user `1001`
RUN chmod 775 /work /work/application \
  && chown -R 1001 /work \
  && chmod -R "g+rwX" /work \
  && chown -R 1001:root /work

EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Пытался явно добавлять в свой проект пакет и файл *com/amazonaws/partitions/endpoints.json*, но не помогло

Так же пытался подключить данный файл как ресурс в докер посредством `-H:IncludeResources="com/amazonaws/partitions/endpoints.json"`, но и это не сработало

В плане развертывания в докере я еще новичок, поэтому скорее всего дико туплю(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено

Как изначально и думал, проблема в том, что докер не может высосать данные из джарника. Поэтому ему нужно помочь это сделать.

Во первых, создаем resources-config.json следующего вида:

```html
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "pattern": ".*\\.xml$"
    },
    {
      "pattern": ".*\\.json$"
    }
  ]
}
```

Далее создаем reflection-config.json:

```html
[
  {
    "name" : "com.amazonaws.partitions.model.Partitions",
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true
  },
  {
    "name" : "com.amazonaws.partitions.model.Partition",
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true
  },
  {
    "name" : "com.amazonaws.partitions.model.Endpoint",
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true
  },
  {
    "name" : "com.amazonaws.partitions.model.Region",
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true
  },
  {
    "name" : "com.amazonaws.partitions.model.Service",
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true
  },
  {
    "name" : "com.amazonaws.partitions.model.CredentialScope",
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true
  },
  {
    "name" : "java.util.HashSet",
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true
  },
  {
    "name" : "com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer",
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true
  }
]
```

Следующим этапом создаем dynamic-proxies.json:

```html
[
  ["org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager", "org.apache.http.pool.ConnPoolControl", "com.amazonaws.http.conn.Wrapped"]
]
```

И напоследок в application.yml добавляем:

```html
quarkus:
  native:
    additional-build-args: -H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=resources-config.json, -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflection-config.json, -H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=dynamic-proxies.json
```

После этого сервак завелся как надо (были потом еще ошибки, но к вопросу не относятся)